# How to create a dictionary and add key value pairs dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, key-value

From post:

*[Sending a JSON array to be received as a Dictionary<string,string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494294/sending-a-json-array-to-be-received-as-a-dictionarystring-string/7196027#7196027)*,

I'm trying to do this same thing as that post. The only issue is that I don't know what the keys and the values are upfront. So I need to be able to dynamically add the key and value pairs and I don't know how to do that.

How can I create that object and add key value pairs dynamically?

I've tried:

```
var vars = [{key:"key", value:"value"}];
vars[0].key = "newkey";
vars[0].value = "newvalue";
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: It works great. console.log(vars); show me[
Object
key: "newkey"
value: "newvalue"
__proto__: Object
]

Comment: Except for it is a list, not a dictionary :\ I think the data is better represented as a list of "pairs" as well, like `list = [["key1","value1"],["key2","value2"]]`. Some other languages have a "pair", or "tuple" type. tldr for actual dict adding: `dict['key'] = "value"`

Comment: The question title and body have nothing in common. Question is about adding a new key into a dict, the body is about adding a key/val pair into a list. I am surprised this has been left like this, and will show up as result for "how to add key to dictionary". Thankfully the answers do indeed answer both questions.

Answer (score 708, accepted):

Use:

```
var dict = []; // Create an empty array

dict.push({
    key:   "keyName",
    value: "the value"
});
// Repeat this last part as needed to add more key/value pairs
```

Basically, you're creating an object literal with two properties (called `key` and `value`) and inserting it (using `push()`) into the array.

---

This does not create a "normal" JavaScript object literal (aka map, aka hash, aka dictionary).
It *is* however creating the structure that OP asked for (and which is illustrated in the other question linked to), which is *an array of object literals*, each with `key` and `value` properties. Don't ask me why that structure was required, but it's the one that was asked for.

But, but, if what you want in a plain JavaScript object - and *not* the structure OP asked for - see [tcll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22315575/167996), though the bracket notation is a bit cumbersome if you just have simple keys that are valid JavaScript names. You can just do this:

```
// Object literal with properties
var dict = {
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2"
  // etc.
};
```

Or use regular dot-notation to set properties after creating an object:

```
// Empty object literal with properties added afterward
var dict = {};
dict.key1 = "value1";
dict.key2 = "value2";
// etc.
```

You *do* want the bracket notation if you've got keys that have spaces in them, special characters, or things like that. E.g:

```
var dict = {};

// This obviously won't work
dict.some invalid key (for multiple reasons) = "value1";

// But this will
dict["some invalid key (for multiple reasons)"] = "value1";
```

You also want bracket notation if your keys are dynamic:

```
dict[firstName + " " + lastName] = "some value";
```

Note that keys (property names) are always strings, and non-string values will be coerced to a string when used as a key. E.g., a `Date` object gets converted to its string representation:

```
dict[new Date] = "today's value";

console.log(dict);
// => {
//      "Sat Nov 04 2016 16:15:31 GMT-0700 (PDT)": "today's value"
//    }
```

Note however that this doesn't necessarily "just work", as many objects will have a string representation like `"[object Object]"` which doesn't make for a non-unique key. So be wary of something like:

```
var objA = { a: 23 },
    objB = { b: 42 };

dict[objA] = "value for objA";
dict[objB] = "value for objB";

console.log(dict);
// => { "[object Object]": "value for objB" }
```

Despite `objA` and `objB` being completely different and unique elements, they both have the same basic string representation: `"[object Object]"`.

The reason `Date` doesn't behave like this is that the `Date` prototype has a custom `toString` method which overrides the default string representation. And you can do the same:

```
// A simple constructor with a toString prototypal method
function Foo() {
  this.myRandomNumber = Math.random() * 1000 | 0;
}

Foo.prototype.toString = function () {
  return "Foo instance #" + this.myRandomNumber;
};

dict[new Foo] = "some value";

console.log(dict);
// => {
//      "Foo instance #712": "some value"
//    }
```

(Note that since the above uses a *random* number, name collisions can still occur very easily. It's just to illustrate an implementation of `toString`.)

So when trying to use objects as keys, JavaScript will use the object's own `toString` implementation, if any, or use the default string representation.

Comment: @CsabaToth No, `dict` is not an associative dictionary. It's an array of objects, each of which is a bit like a dictionary with two keys: "key" and "value".

Comment: What you have there is an array that is merely named 'dict'.

Comment: Appreciate the update and follow up extra information.

Answer (score 501):

Use:

```
var dict = {};

dict['key'] = "testing";

console.log(dict);
```

It works just like Python :)

Console output:

```
Object {key: "testing"}
```

Comment: This is certainly the best approach to building a dictionary, and IS the correct answer!

Comment: Very important to initialized with brackets `{}` rather than parenthesis

Comment: I also use basic objects as dictionaries like this. Glad to see that's the right way!

Comment: @Jaider: braces: `{}`; brackets: `[]`; parenthesis: `()`... hope that clears up your confusion ;)

Comment: 'Beauty' of javascript!
Object IS actualy a key value pair dictionary itself

Comment: If this dictionary has multiple items, how to iterate through each item and display.

Comment: @MerinNakarmi: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748781/loop-through-a-hashmap-in-javascript

Comment: @TrevordeKoekkoek the dictionary array holds the KeyValuePair objects, so accepted answer is correct.

Comment: Does the key have to be a string? I am trying to use a Date object, but it's not working.

Comment: @Azurespot the key can be anything hashable, keys are ordered by hash after all, which in python3 differs each run.

Answer (score 59):

It’s as simple as:

```
var blah = {}; // Make a new dictionary (empty)
```

or

```
var blah = {key: value, key2: value2}; // Make a new dictionary with two pairs
```

Then

```
blah.key3 = value3; // Add a new key/value pair
blah.key2; // Returns value2
blah['key2']; // Also returns value2
```

Comment: @KenEucker I think it's useful to have wrong answers in questions like this. Especially if someone explains why they're wrong, it's a good learning resource.

Answer (score 34):

Since you've stated that you want a dictionary object (and **not an array** like I assume some understood) I think this is what you are after:

```
var input = [{key:"key1", value:"value1"},{key:"key2", value:"value2"}];

var result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    result[input[i].key] = input[i].value;
}

console.log(result); // Just for testing
```

Comment: The other solution using .push into an array works for my uses, but I assume this would also work if I tried it.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what a Dictionary object is, your question is misleading then. How would you retrieve a value by key from your array?

Comment: I am using JSON.stringify on this object and then catching it with a controller in MVC 3. This is just so that it is formatted properly before stringifying it and sending it along.

Answer (score 31):

JavaScript's `Object` **is** in itself like a dictionary. No need to reinvent the wheel.

```
var dict = {};

// Adding key-value -pairs
dict['key'] = 'value'; // Through indexer
dict.anotherKey = 'anotherValue'; // Through assignment

// Looping through
for (var item in dict) {
  console.log('key:' + item + ' value:' + dict[item]);
  // Output
  // key:key value:value
  // key:anotherKey value:anotherValue
}

// Non existent key
console.log(dict.notExist); // undefined

// Contains key?
if (dict.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
  // Remove item
  delete dict.key;
}

// Looping through
for (var item in dict) {
  console.log('key:' + item + ' value:' + dict[item]);
  // Output
  // key:anotherKey value:anotherValue
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wka4heap/1/)

Comment: But with restrictions on what values the keys can take? Reserved words, etc.?

Answer (score 15):

You can use maps with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), like this:

```
var sayings = new Map();
sayings.set('dog', 'woof');
sayings.set('cat', 'meow');
```

Answer (score 13):

With [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015), you can do this:

```
let cake = '';

let pan = {
  [cake]: '',
};

// Output -> { '': '' }
```

**Old Way** ([vanilla JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software))

```
let cake = '';
let pan = {};
pan[cake] = '';

// Output -> { '': '' }
```

Comment: I like this solution, as it is updated for the modern time and is pretty elegant. Thank you for your contribution. This would have been a valid solution for what I needed at the time.

Answer (score 9):

I happened to walk across this question looking for something similar. It gave me enough info to run a test to get the answer I wanted. So if anyone else wants to know how to dynamically add to or lookup a {key: 'value'} pair in a JavaScript object, this test should tell you all you might need to know.

```
var dictionary = {initialkey: 'initialValue'};
var key = 'something';
var key2 =  'somethingElse';
var value = 'value1';
var value2 = 'value2';
var keyInitial = 'initialkey';

console.log(dictionary[keyInitial]);

dictionary[key] =value;
dictionary[key2] = value2;
console.log(dictionary);
```

output

```
initialValue
{ initialkey: 'initialValue',
  something: 'value1',
  somethingElse: 'value2' }
```

Comment: This is not a question. What you should do instead is ask the question and then answer it yourself. That would be much easier to understand and organize.

Comment: thanks @SalmonKiller i was unsure of proper terminology to write my own question and expect it to be understood but then i happened across this in my search all the information was there but spread out between several answers so i answered the concept of this question in a way that would answer it for someone else who stumbled on to this question looking for the same thing as me

Comment: LOL. I was reviewing this and it looked like a question instead of an answer. Sorry, man!

Comment: Thank you for adding this. You could also put it into a fiddle like the answer above.

Answer (score 7):

```
var dictionary = {};//create new object
dictionary["key1"] = value1;//set key1
var key1 = dictionary["key1"];//get key1
```

Comment: for some added performance, you should reference `key1 = dictionary.key1` rather than index `key1 = dictionary["key1"]`

Answer (score 7):

In modern JavaScript ([ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015)/ES2015), one should use the *Map* data structure for a dictionary. The Map data structure in ES6 lets you use arbitrary values as keys.

```
const map = new Map();
map.set("true", 1);
map.set("false", 0);
```

In you are still using [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2009), the correct way to create dictionary is to create object without a prototype in the following way.

```
var map = Object.create(null);
map["true"] = 1;
map["false"] = 0;
```

There are many advantages of creating a dictionary without a prototype object. The below blog posts are worth reading on this topic.

[dict-pattern](http://2ality.com/2013/10/dict-pattern.html)

[objects-as-maps](http://2ality.com/2012/01/objects-as-maps.html)

Answer (score 7):

First initialise the array globally:

```
var dict = []
```

Add the object into the dictionary

```
dict.push(
     { key: "One",value: false},
     { key: "Two",value: false},
     { key: "Three",value: false});
```

Output:

```
   [0: {key: "One", value: false}
    1: {key: "Two", value: false}
    2: {key: "Three", value: false}]
```

Update the object from the dictionary

```
Object.keys(dict).map((index) => {
  if (index == 1){
    dict[index].value = true
  }
});
```

Output:

```
   [0: {key: "One", value: false},
    1: {key: "Two", value: true},
    2: {key: "Three", value: false}]
```

Delete an object from the dictionary

```
Object.keys(dict).map((index) => {
      if (index == 2){
        dict.splice(index)
      }
    });
```

Output:

```
    [0: {key: "One", value: false},
     1: {key: "Two", value: true}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could create a class Dictionary so you can interact with the Dictionary list easily:

```js
class Dictionary {
  constructor() {
    this.items = {};
  }
  has(key) {
    return key in this.items;
  }
  set(key,value) {
    this.items[key] = value;
  }
  delete(key) {
    if( this.has(key) ){
      delete this.items[key]
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

var d = new Dictionary();
d.set(1, "value1")
d.set(2, "value2")
d.set(3, "value3")
console.log(d.has(2));
d.delete(2);
console.log(d.has(2));
```

Answer (score 4):

An improvement on `var dict = {}` is to use `var dict = Object.create(null)`.

This will create an empty object that does **not** have `Object.prototype` as its prototype.

```
var dict1 = {};
if (dict1["toString"]){
    console.log("Hey, I didn't put that there!")
}

var dict2 = Object.create(null);
if (dict2["toString"]){
    console.log("This line won't run :)")
}
```

Comment: Good point, as you would otherwise get a dictionary full of:

`__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: ​constructor: function Object()
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
hasProperty: function value(prop)
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
toString: function toString()
​valueOf: function valueOf()`

Comment: Lifesaver! As a newbie I was a bit confused when `dict["constructor"].item` kept crashing my app.

Answer (score 4):

Use a one-liner for creating a key value pair:

```
let result = { ["foo"]: "some value" };
```

And some iterator function like `reduce` to dynamically convert an array to a dictionary

```js
var options = [
  { key: "foo", value: 1 },
  { key: "bar", value: {id: 2, name: "two"} },
  { key: "baz", value: {["active"]: true} },
];

var result = options.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  accumulator[current.key] = current.value;
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem... but within a *for* loop. The top solution did not work (when using variables (and not strings) for the parameters of the push function), and the others did not account for key values based on variables. I was surprised this approach (which is common in PHP) worked...

```
// Example dict/JSON
var iterateDict = {'record_identifier': {'content':'Some content', 'title':'Title of my Record'},
  'record_identifier_2': {'content':'Some  different content', 'title':'Title of my another Record'} };

var array = [];

// Key to reduce the 'record' to
var reduceKey = 'title';

for(key in iterateDict)
 // Ultra-safe variable checking...
 if(iterateDict[key] !== undefined && iterateDict[key][reduceKey] !== undefined)
  // Build element to new array key
   array[key] = iterateDict[key][reduceKey];
```

Answer (score 2):

In case if someone needs to create a dictionary object dynamically you can use the following code snippet

```js
let vars = [{key:"key", value:"value"}, {key:"key2", value:"value2"}];
let dict = {}
vars.map(varItem => {
             dict[varItem.key] = varItem.value
         })

console.log(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the dictionary like

```
var vars = {
    "key1": "Search",
    "key2": "View"
};
```

And access it like

```
console.log(vars["key1"]);
```