# JS fill Object as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

can you tell me how to fill this element as an array

```
testdata = [
    {
        key: "one",
        y: 200
    },
    {
        key: "two",
        y: 300
    }
       ];
```

example:

```
testdata=[];
testdata[]="one";
testdata[]="two";
```

Comment: You want to create an array of objects? From what?

Comment: I want create object from array.

Comment: Could you give a better example with given input and expected output?

Comment: I I found a solution

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You mind sharing that with us? Otherwise I would advice deleting the question altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to write a function that constructs a json object. Call it CreateObject and then you can just use a for loop like:

```
var list = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   var obj = CreateObject(i); //add other params if you need
   list.push(obj);
}
return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want two dimensional JS array

```
var items = [[11,22],[33,44],[55,66]];
alert(items[0][0]); // 11;
```

Or i think you want dictionary object like following

```
var dict = []; // create an empty array

dict.push({
    key:   "keyName",
    value: "the value"
});
```

**reference taken from**  : [How to create dictionary and add key value pairs dynamically in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196212/how-to-create-dictionary-and-add-key-value-pairs-dynamically-in-javascript)

Comment: I would like to be able to cycle and to fill