# How to map an array to a date?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In C#, I would use the following Dictionary

```
Dictionary << Date, int []>>
```

for having an array bound to a particular date. What would be the simplest way in JS to achieve the same?

I need to be able to alter the values in the integer array.

Comment: you can create something almost the same in JS. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196212/how-to-create-dictionary-and-add-key-value-pairs-dynamically/22315575

Comment: You can use the JavaScript `Map` class, but be warned that equality comparison for Map keys is less flexible than in Java (and I would strongly suspect C#).

Comment: just remember IE 8 < does not support Map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve an equal behaviour in Js in various ways.

`Dicitionary` could be replaced by a `Map`, or just an object (`{}`) with dynamic keys, however if you use an object you can only use strings as keys, anything else will be converted to a string. There is also a `Date` object in JS, however two dates representing the same date in time do not match:

```
 const a = new Date(0), b = new Date(0);
 console.log(a === b); // false
```

therefore they would not get stored in the same entry in the Map. Instead you could just stringify the Date, as strings are conpared by value. the `int[]` would just be an array of numbers in js.

```
  const date1 = new Date(0);
  const date1b = new Date(0);

 const obj = {};
 const map = new Map;

 obj[date1] = [1, 2, 3];
 // equals:
 obj[date1.toString()] = [1, 2, 3];

 map.set(date1, [1, 2, 3]);
 map.set(date1.toString(), [3, 4, 5]);

 console.log(
   obj[date1b], // [1, 2, 3]
   map.get(date1b), // undefined
   map.get(date1b.toString()), // [3, 4, 5]
 );
```

> I only need to group by days

In that case, you'd have to generate a number or string out of the Date that only contains the day:

```
 (new Date()).toString().split("T")[0] // 2018-12-11
```

Then use that string as the Maps / objects key.

Comment: I retrieve dates from the database and using Moment when storing them.

Comment: @John then i guess the timestamp is already a string (or a number?) in that case just take that.

Comment: May I ask - I realized the date is also saved with its time component but I only need to group by days, how can I only use the date component? I guess otherwise I will never have two records under the same key as the milliseconds will not match :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the timestamp of that date as a key for a js object.

For example, let's say you want to map date a to array b:

```js
const a = new Date();
const b = [1, 2, 3];


const c = {
  [a.getTime()]: b,
};
```

in this case, c would be an object or hash map from date to array.

Comment: In particular with Date instances this is not a bad idea, because the timestamp comparison is reliable and works with different Date instances. That's probably more like what the OP would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you are using `momentjs`, you could use the moment [**`unix`**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) or `toDate().getTime()` to `to get the date in ms` and then utilize either an object or `Map` to get what you need:

```js
let date1 = moment().unix()
let date2 = moment().add(7, 'days').unix()

let dict = {}  // using object

dict[date1] = [1,2,3]
dict[date2] = [4,5,6]

console.log('dict via Object', dict[date1], dict[date2])

let dict2 = new Map()  // using Map

dict2.set(date1, [1,2,3])
dict2.set(date2, [4,5,6])

console.log('dict via Map', dict2.get(date1), dict2.get(date2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have a small typo on `getTime`