# Is there a simple way in Javascript to encode a string using a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, string, encoding

I want to use a simple substitution code, with (perhaps) a dictionary. In Python, it's straightforward but I want to write it in JavaScript.

```
dict = {}
dict["c"]="f"
dict["u"]="i"
dict["t"]="j" .... 

for x in message:
    print (dict[x].upper())
```

Comment: Are you confused on how to make a dictionary? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196212/how-to-create-dictionary-and-add-key-value-pairs-dynamically

Your question isn't very specific with the code sample.

Comment: You can just create an object for this job. Javascript objects are like python dictionaries in that you can use string as key and retrieve a value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let dict = {}
dict["c"]="f"
dict["u"]="i"
dict["t"]="j"

for(let key in dict){
  console.log(dict[key].toUpperCase())
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks.