# what does mean by this line of code in JS obj[{key:"value"}] = "value";

Tags: javascript, object

```js
let obj = {};
            obj[{key:"instagram"}] = "Akrixa";
            obj[{key:"facebook"}] = "Coding with Akrixa";

            console.log(obj[{key: "instagram"}]);
```

This is a problem in which I'm confused with 2nd and 3rd line of code, what does by those lines?

Comment: This doesn't do anything useful (try `console.log(obj)`)

Comment: okay, Can you tell me the meaning?

Comment: Basically it is asign the value of particular key

Answer (score 2):

`obj[{key:"instagram"}] = "Akrixa"` is equivalent to
`obj[({key:"instagram"}).toString()] = "Akrixa"` since objects are keyed by strings. So it's equivalent to
`obj["[object Object]"] = "Akrixa"`

Answer (score 0):

I think because obj[{key:"instagram"}] and obj[{key:"facebook"}] are the same object. When assign value for it, it has the same value. More detail: [How to create dictionary and add key–value pairs dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196212/how-to-create-dictionary-and-add-key-value-pairs-dynamically). I wish its help you

Answer (score -1):

The second line `obj[{key:"instagram"}] = "Akrixa";` creates a key within your obj `[{key:"instagram}]` (which is an object inside an array) and then sets the value of that key to `Akrixa`, and the third line does the same but with a different key and value.

It might be better to use `obj["instagram"] = "Akrixa"` and `obj["facebook"] = "Coding with Akrixa"` as to avoid excessive complication, and you can then refer to it with `obj["instagram"]` etc.

```js
let obj = {};
obj["instagram"] = "Akrixa";
obj["facebook"] = "Coding with Akrixa";
console.log(obj["instagram"]);
```