# How to create dynamic dictionary and add-remove key–value pairs?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I refer below post but did not get it properly 
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494294/sending-a-json-array-to-be-received-as-a-dictionarystring-string/7196027#7196027)

I was tried to do this same thing as that post. The only issue is that I don’t know what the keys and the values are upfront. So I need to be able to dynamically add and remove the key and value pairs and I don’t know how to achieve that.

Is anyone know how to create that object and add key value pairs dynamically and perform crud operation on it?

I’ve tried:

```
var dict = [{key:"key", value:"value"}];
dict[0].key = "keys";
dict[0].value = "vals";
console.log(dict);
// return null value of dict object.
```

So that doesn’t work.
Thank you

Comment: You can simply try:-  dict["key"] = value, you can get all the keys and values using Object.keys(dict) and Object.values(dict).

Comment: it is working. https://jsfiddle.net/srycmwjo/

Comment: You could use a `Map`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Examples

Comment: To get all keys of your datastructure try `dirct.map(({key}) => key)` in JS6.

Comment: yes now i'm able to added new keys with value but how can i delete dynamically ?

Comment: You can iterate over the array of keys using Object.keys(dict) which will return array of keys and delete the key value pair you want to using map as iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried dynamically using .set(key, value) and it's work

```
var dict = new Map();
dict.set("key1", "value1");

for (var [key, value] of dict) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).
Map object has functions to set keys and values dynamically using  `.set(key, value)`

```
var dict = new Map();
dict.set("key1", "value1");
dict.set("key2", "value2");
dict.set("key3", "value3");

for (var [key, value] of dict) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
```